# EBS/AWS With Node/angular2 app keeps setting port to 8081

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services

In my angular2 app, on EBS, i define an PORT environment variable. I then use that port variable, or at least I'm trying, to use it inside my node server.

```
console.log("Express Serversss listening on " + global.process.env.PORT + " for env " + global.process.env.NODE_ENV);
```

I then set my port to 3001, inside EBS config area. But when i then deploy the application to EBS, it will always give me:

'Express Servers listening on 8081 for env staging:
Port 8081 is already in use'

However, no where in my Code do have port 8081 declared anywhere. So I'm not quite sure where this port number is even coming from.

Thoughts?

Comment: It looks like it is being overrides to 8081. Other process.env variable stay the same...But the PORT doesn't.

Comment: Well, this is old question but in case if someone else need this, AWS uses the default port 8080 for node stack, if you want to override port you can change the elasticbean config 

```# 01_envar.config
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment:
    PORT: 8081 // What ever port you want
    NODE_ENV: production```

If you are changing the portm, then you also need to fix nginx configuration (reverse proxy config)

-Neelesh

Answer (score 0):

I dont have it up in front of me right now, but generally how you'd do it in your elastic beanstalk application environment settings, you can specify environment variables OR update the start command for your app to include a PORT variable.

- Using environment variables, you'd say PORT=2222 (or whatever you want)
- or, you the command could be changed from `node myserver.js` to `PORT=2222 node myserver.js`

Also, in your actual code, you'll need to make sure your app is not explicitly programmed to run on some specific port. if it is, you'll have to add support for the port you're trying to run it on.

hope that sets you on the right path to making it work. it took me a while to figure out my first time using beanstalk.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem. Not only was i thinking i could override the port that AWS is assigning to process.env.PORT, which i couldn't, i was also creating socket server before the actual node server. Because the node express generator puts the server initialization inside bin/www, i needed to pass my server to socket.io after its created.

```
 var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3001');
app.set('port', port);

/**
 * Create HTTP server.
 */

var server = http.createServer(app);

/**
 * Listen on provided port, on all network interfaces.
 */

server.listen(port);
server.on('error', onError);
server.on('listening', onListening);


var io = require('socket.io')(server);
require('../routes/socket.js')(io);
```

This worked!